# How to add ad code in wordpress Single page without affecting the second single page template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am using two different template for single page. One with sidebar and another one without sidebar.

Now i want to inject the ad code only in the sidebar template.

Could any one give me a code for this one.

Note:

1. The ad is automatically inserted after every second paragraph. And i have the code.

   add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

   ```
   function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {


           if ( is_single() && ! is_admin()) {
               return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
           }


       return $content;
   }


   function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
       $closing_p = '</p>';
       $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
       foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

           if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
               $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
           }

           if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
               $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
           }
       }

       return implode( '', $paragraphs );
   }
   ```

The above code display the ad code both in sidebar template and no sidebar template. But actually i want to display the ad code only in sidebar template. Could any one please help me how to do it.

Comment: you need to give more information here, you should prob upload your single.php or whatever template into pastebin. Whats the difference between a sidebar being shown and not showing are they set by widgets etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which template is used with [`get_page_template_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug):

```
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() && get_page_template_slug() == 'template-sidebar.php') {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code on your single php file

```
if (is_page(12)) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }
```

Thanks.